# UITableView creates first row to last

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I tried to make simple UIPopover with grouped table view. Everything is fine but first row is empty and it's data is in the last row. Whats wrong with my code?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];

static NSString *kCellTextField_ID = @"CellTextField_ID";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID];
if (cell == nil) {
        // a new cell needs to be created
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
} else {
    // a cell is being recycled, remove the old edit field (if it contains one of our tagged edit fields)
    UIView *viewToCheck = nil;
    viewToCheck = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kViewTag];
    if (viewToCheck) [viewToCheck removeFromSuperview]; 
}
if (section == 1 && row == 0) {
    UITextView *textView = [[self.sisalto objectAtIndex: row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
} else {
    UITextField *textField = [[self.sisalto objectAtIndex: row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
}
return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need the if for the "section" and "row" when you are doing exactly the same in both?

Comment: @jodm They're not exactly the same. `UITextView` vs `UITextField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was the problem. It was this sentence:

```
if (section == 1 && row == 0){
   UITextView *textView = [[self.sisalto objectAtIndex: row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
}
```

It set just created cell with first value in datasource (sisalto). Obliviously, it should set first value of section 2 in datasource. When this is corrected everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the problem. Look at the following code.

```
if (section == 1 && row == 0) {
    UITextView *textView = [[self.sisalto objectAtIndex: row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
}
```

`section == 1` indicates that you have two sections and your setting the first item of the second section to the first item of the array. That might be why it shows up last in your table view.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You're right about two sections. There should be two groups. This isn't the problem. Without if statement result is exactly same. First cell is last one and first is empty. I should mention that if I flip through popover and tableview needs to be redrawn it is drawn correctly exept last cell witch is empty.

Comment: Is there any way to set indexpath variable before view draw begins. That might help?